# Accommodate VS2013 project to VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, jsoncpp

So I've recently upgraded `VS2013` to `VS2015` and I'm still struggling  accommodating the code & project's definitions to make it work.

I have dozens of projects in my solution. I also use [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) as an additional lib.

When compiling a single project, I get this error:

```
3>LINK : fatal error C1047: The object or library file '..\Libs\json_cpp\build\vs71\release\lib_json\json_vc71_libmt.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
```

So I've open the `Libs\json_cpp\makefiles\vs71\jsoncpp.sln` with `VS2015` and rebuild the solution.

that didn't help.

#### Possible Reason

My projects are all using *Platform Toolset* `Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)`
while the jsoncpp *Platform Toolset* is `Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)`

If this is indeed the issue so the obvious solution is to have both solutions compile in the same *Platform Toolset* `Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)`.

#### Possible Solution

So, I've tried that. and got countless of these warnings:

```
json_value.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: static int const std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::digits10" (?digits10@?$numeric_limits@G@std@@2HB) already defined in json_writer.obj; second definition ignored
```

Anybody else suffered from this agonizing process of `VS` upgrade and can share some insights?

Comment: *Possible Reason* seems like it definitely is the reason; mixing compilers/platform toolsets/... for C++ is never going to work (unless you export just a plain C API which isn't the case here). jsoncpp uses cmake, why not start from scratch and invoke CMake to create files for VS2015 and see if it builds without warnings/errors? And file a bug report to jsoncpp if it doesn't. Or, if you don't need XP support, try everything with the v140 toolset.

Comment: What @stijn said (try building from scratch) + are you using the latest (or at least recent) version of jsoncpp?

Comment: @conio jsoncpp support `c++11`. what do you mean by from scratch?

Comment: I mean what stijn wrote - recreate the VS solution file. But on second thought I see that the jsoncpp readme recommends including the jsoncpp code directly in your solution. Is there a reason not to do that? https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp#using-jsoncpp-in-your-project